# Could the evil creature come to water alone?

Tags: plot-explanation, dreadout

In the 2019 Indonesian movie, *DreadOut*, which is based on a video game of the same name, a group of schoolteens decide to go to a mysterious house in order to film and gain fame on Instagram.

They find skin papers which only the titular character, Linda, can see the letters on them and read them. When she reads the paper the sealed door on the floor opens magically and it turns out to be a portal to a haunted jungle with dead people and evil creatures.

The portal is a tube pool of water. The characters accidentally fall inside the pool. All of them except for Linda and Jessica are able to come back to the room.

Linda and Jessica come out of the other end and find themselves in the said haunted jungle. There they find a house with an evil creature resembling a lady in red kebaya (a traditional Southeast Asian dress) who can fly on the air near the ground and has sharp teeth.

They flee to get back to the pool while the creature is chasing them. Just before jumping to the pool Jessica falls on the ground, but Linda jumps and gets back to the room.

In the room Linda inform the others that Jessica is still there. Suddenly, a haunted Jessica gets out of the pool and tries to kill her friends while wearing the same kebaya (the evil creature can't be seen outside her realm, but Linda can see her through her camera phone and it turns out she is puppeting Jessica).

**My question**: If Jessica was able to jump at the pool with Linda could the evil creature still come to the pool and enter the real world? In other words, is it a requirement for the creature to haunt someone to be able to enter the pool and hence, the real world?